# Python, client-server application, does not connect

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, server, client

For some reason, the next elementary program connects the client to the server only from the second time. And so every time after restarting the server. Can someone explain the reason for this behavior and how to solve this problem? Maybe it's because asyncore is only used on the server side? (Windows 7, Python 3) Thank you in advance!

Сlient:

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket()
host = 'localhost'
port = 8081
tempr = port
sock.connect((host,port))
```

Server:

```
import asyncore 
import socket 
import time

class EchoHandler(asyncore.dispatcher_with_send):

def handle_read(self):
  data = self.recv(1024)

class EchoServer(asyncore.dispatcher):
  def __init__(self, host, port):
  asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
  self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  self.set_reuse_addr()
  self.bind((host, port))
  self.listen(2)

  def handle_accept(self):
    pair = self.accept()
    if pair is not None:
      sock, addr = pair
      print ('Incoming connection from %s' % repr(addr))
      handler = EchoHandler(sock)

def main():
  host = 'localhost'
  port = 8081
  server = EchoServer(host, port)

  print ('Server %s running'% port)
  asyncore.loop()

if __name__ == '__main__': 
   main()
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: There is no errors and no exceptions, but the function handle_accept() is executed only from the second attempt to connect the client.

Comment: I'm  away from the documentation and have not familiarized myself with `asyncore`, but I'm going to guess that you shouldn't call `accept` in `handle_except`. The server probably calls that function after accepting a connection, so it is redundant.

Comment: It's strange. I took the server code from here (from below): https://docs.python.org/2/library/asyncore.html

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of `socket` is to `send()` and `recv()` (receive) data between client and server. You must send some data (even an empty string must be sent) to server after connecting to server and server may return some data to client and/or just close connection.

my_client.py

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(('localhost', 8081))
sock.send(b'data from client')
print(sock.recv(32))
sock.close()
```

my_server.py

```
import asyncore
import socket
import time


class EchoHandler(asyncore.dispatcher_with_send):
    def handle_read(self):
        data = self.recv(1024)
        print('data from client', data)
        self.send(b'data from server')
        self.close()


class EchoServer(asyncore.dispatcher):
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
        self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.set_reuse_addr()
        self.bind((host, port))
        self.listen(2)

    def handle_accept(self):
        pair = self.accept()
        if pair is not None:
            sock, addr = pair
            print('Incoming connection from %s' % repr(addr))
            handler = EchoHandler(sock)


def main():
    host = 'localhost'
    port = 8081
    server = EchoServer(host, port)

    print('Server %s running' % port)
    asyncore.loop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

**Update:**
You do get an error: `OSError: [WinError 10038]` because you are closing socket in server without reading all data from client. The same is happening in client side too.
In Python documentation it is explicitly stated that these are `very basic` examples.

Use method `sendall()` to be sure that all data is sent. Method `send()` does not guaranty sending of all data.

You must read data from socket with a `while` loop like this:

my_client.py

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(('localhost', 8081))
sock.sendall(b'data from client')

chunk = b''  # socket.recv returns bytes
data = b''  # defined before to avoid NameError 
while True:
    chunk = sock.recv(32)
    if chunk:
        data += chunk
    else:
        break

print(data)
sock.close()
```

my_server.py

```
import asyncore
import socket
import time


class EchoHandler(asyncore.dispatcher_with_send):
    def handle_read(self):

        chunk = b''  # socket.recv returns bytes
        data = b''  # defined before to avoid NameError
        while True:
            chunk = self.recv(1024)
            if chunk:
                data += chunk
            else:
                break

        print('data from client', data)
        self.sendall(b'data from server')
        self.close()


class EchoServer(asyncore.dispatcher):
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
        self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.set_reuse_addr()
        self.bind((host, port))
        self.listen(2)

    def handle_accept(self):
        pair = self.accept()
        if pair is not None:
            sock, addr = pair
            print('Incoming connection from %s' % repr(addr))
            handler = EchoHandler(sock)


def main():
    host = 'localhost'
    port = 8081
    server = EchoServer(host, port)

    print('Server %s running' % port)
    asyncore.loop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! After the second restart of the client (the server is running) I receive an exception (<class 'OSError'>:[WinError 10038]

Comment: @Viktor Please provide full error (including line of occurrence) next time. It won't take you 2 weeks to get an answer. You are lucky I had free time checking old answers! `OSError: [WinError 10038] an operation was attempted on something that is not a socket`. Answer updated.